# C# XNA Matrices - find out the current locatin after matrix multiplication

Tags: c#, matrix, xna, matrix-multiplication

i am making 3D Simulation of Solar System

for every planet i have an instance of class **Celestial Body**. I am using the following code for revolution and rotation of sun, planets & their moons.

```
world = Matrix.CreateTranslation(0,0,0) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(rotation) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(position) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(revolution);
```

- rotation is my float variable for rotation of planet around its own axis
- revolution is my float variable for revolution of planet in orbit
- position is to my vector3 variable to put the body in orbit or at its radius from center e.g `postion = new Vector3(70,0,0)`

Now it works really fine.

But the problem is i need to locate \ get the position of my planet, to where it has been translated after the Matrix multiplication literally in x,y,x co-ordinates.

**How To ?** get the current X , Y , Z coordinates of my planet

the other option for me would be to use some maths formula that calculates a 2D circle for me.

Comment: i am sorry i am unaware of world.Translation i.e Matrix.translation... please teach

Comment: I added an answer with a few more details. Let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `Matrix.Translation`. This gives you the x, y, z co-odinates of the matrix that it's called on in a `Vector3`.

So, to get the new position, you should use

```
Vector3 newPosition = world.Translation;
```

after your calculations.